# Getting field by name using reflect panics when checking IsZero

Tags: go, struct, reflection

I have a piece of reflection code that attempts to get the field on a struct by name and then checks if the field exists:

```
type test struct {
   A bool
   B bool
}

t := new(test)
metaValue := reflect.ValueOf(t).Elem()
field := metaValue.FieldByName(name)
if field.IsZero() {
    glog.Errorf("Field %s was not on the struct", inner)
}
```

According to the documentation on `FieldByName`, this function should return a zero value if no field was found. However, the very next line panics with the error:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.IsZero on zero Value

goroutine 268 [running]:
reflect.Value.IsZero({0x0, 0x0, 0x112a974})
        reflect/value.go:1475 +0x27f
```

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46320), this should only happen if the Value contains nil (i.e. no type) and `IsValid` should be used instead. Why is this happening?

Comment: Just a tip: avoid using `new(T)` as much as possible. It's better to just create a new literal (`t := test{}` or `t := &test{}`). There are certain cases where the use of `new` makes sense, but those are few and far between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Value.IsZero()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.IsZero) reports whether the wrapped value is the zero value of its type. This is not the same as the `reflect.Value` itself being zero (zero value of `reflect.Value` which is a struct).

Also note that `t` in your code is not a struct value, its a pointer to struct. Use [`Value.Elem()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Elem) to nagivate to the wrapped struct value (or don't start from a pointer).

If the field does not exist, [`Value.FieldByName()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.FieldByName) returns the zero value of [`reflect.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value), not a non-zero `reflect.Value` holding the zero value of some type; there is no type info if a field is not found.

So to check if the field does not exist, check if the `reflect.Value` itself is zero, by comparing it to `reflect.Value{}`:

```
if field == (reflect.Value{}) {
    log.Printf("Field %s was not on the struct", name)
}
```

Testing it:

```
type test struct {
    A bool
    B bool
    x bool
}

v := new(test)
metaValue := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()

for _, name := range []string{"A", "x", "y"} {
    field := metaValue.FieldByName(name)
    if field == (reflect.Value{}) {
        log.Printf("Field %s was not on the struct", name)
    }
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YKT34pfpUAG)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Field y was not on the struct
```